# PDFBox: Difference between PDPage and PDPageNode

Tags: java, pdfbox

So, I'm new to PDFBox, and I'm writing a class that uses this library to add an image to specific coordinates on an existing page of a PDF document.

So far, everything is going great, but there's one thing that worries me.

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(pageNumber);
```

That's basically how I'm getting the specific page to add the image to. What I'm worried about is the documentation for the getAllPages() method indicates it returns PDPage and PDPageNode objects. In my tests so far, I seem to only be getting PDPages, so I've been good, but I don't want a PDPageNode to show up one day and break my code with a ClassCastException.

So, what's the difference between these two classes, and how can I avoid what I'm worried about?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, you will get PDPage objects (in 1.8.10). The javadoc clearly tells "This method will return a flat list of all PDPage objects in this document" and the source code in PDPageNode confirms this:

```
    for( int i=0; i<kids.size(); i++ )
    {
        // ignore duplicates (from malformed PDFs)
        if (!seen.contains(kids.get(i)))
        {
            COSBase obj = kids.getObject( i );
            if (obj instanceof COSDictionary)
            {
                COSDictionary kid = (COSDictionary)obj;
                if( COSName.PAGE.equals( kid.getDictionaryObject( COSName.TYPE ) ) )
                {
                    result.add( new PDPage( kid ) );
                }
                else
                {
                    if (recurse)
                    {
                        getAllKids(result, kid, recurse);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.add( new PDPageNode( kid ) );
                    }
                }
            }
            seen.add(kids.get(i));
        }
    }
```

If you 're just starting with PDFBox, I recommend you use 2.0, the API is easier:

```
/**
 * Returns the page at the given index.
 *
 * @param pageIndex the page index
 * @return the page at the given index.
 */
public PDPage getPage(int pageIndex)
```

You will not need the PDPageNode class as an ordinary user. The class is used because some nodes are not leafs, i.e. page objects are organised in a tree in a PDF and not as a list. But getAllPages() will deliver these as a list for you.